# How to copy and paste the content of a contenteditable element which contains a custom element in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, contenteditable

This is a very special question. I use the German website [gutefrage](https://www.gutefrage.net/). This website uses a modified [Quill](https://quilljs.com/) as the editor. [Here](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage_hinzufuegen) you can use the editor. If you press the enter key, a new paragraph is started. If you press SHIFT+ enter, a line break is triggered. The line break, however, is not implemented using the `BR`-element, but they use a custom HTML-element, called `gf-br`. Therefore, one cannot just copy a text like a poem, since every line break is converted into a paragraph automatically.

This is why, I decided to write a tool which "prepares" the text, before I insert it into the editor. The tool converts every `br` into a `gf-br`. If there are two `br`s after each other, they are converted in only one `br`. This is what I have:

```js
function modify() {
  var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
  text = text.split(/<br[\s]?[\/]?>[\s]?<br[\s]?[\/]?>/).join('[<[<break>]>]');
  text = text.split(/<br[\s]?[\/]?>/).join('<gf-br></gf-br>');
  text = text.split('[<[<break>]>]').join('<br />');
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
}

#text {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(90vh - 10px);
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="modify();">Modify</button>
<div id="text" contenteditable></div>
```

One inserts any text, e. g. [this](https://codepen.io/tavkomann/full/pVBgNB/), into the contenteditable `div`. Now, one presses the button and copies the result into the gutefrage-editor. It should look exactly as before.

### The Problem

This works perfectly with Chrome. However, Firefox removes any custom HTML-elements like `gf-br`. I tried to insert any content into this element and I also tried to display the result in a non-`contenteditable` element. It does not work.

Is there any chance to do anything without using a user script? If you have a question or need any additional information, just ask.